# CakePHP: virtual fields containing model related data fields

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I've got a model Employee which belongsTo an Address-model. When I fetch data from the Employees model, the associated Address record gets fetched too. Additionally, the Address model has a virtualField full_name. This looks like this:

```
Array 
(
[0] => Array
       (
        [Employee] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [address_id] => 33
                [username] => ...
                ...
            )

        [Address] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33
                [firstname] => Blah
                [full_name] => Blah Blubb
                ...
            )

    )

[1] => Array  (
        [Employee] => Array   (
                [id] => 2
                ...
```

I want to have included this virtualField in the Employee part of the data array too, like

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
        [Employee] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [full_name] => Blah Blubb
                ...
            )
```

Tis isn't possible to solve by just adding

```
$virtualFields = array(
    'full_name' => 'CONCAT_WS(" ", Address.firstname, Address.surname)',
);
```

to the Employees model, as the Cookbook [states](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1642/Limitations-of-virtualFields) 
There is a solution proposed ("copy virtualFields from one model to another at runtime when you need to access them"), but I don't understand this solution. Where do I have to place this? In the controller? In the model in the find function?

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing this by hand now in the afterFind model callback function:

```
array_walk($results,function(&$a){
        if(isset($a['Address']['full_name'])) {
            $a['Employee']['full_name'] = $a['Address']['full_name'];
            unset($a['Address']);
        }
    });
```

Might be it's not nice, but it works.

Comment: What happens when Address['full_name'] isn't set?  There's a lot of situations where you can't count on the related data being there, such as a find('list') or a find originating in related model.  Any code dependent on finding a correct $a['Employee']['full_name'] fails.  The reason I ask is because I'm running into the same situation.

Answer (score 4):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields#Virtual-fields-and-model-aliases-1632

> The implementation of virtualFields in 1.3 has a few limitations.
>   First you cannot use virtualFields on associated models for
>   conditions, order, or fields arrays. Doing so will generally result in
>   an SQL error as the fields are not replaced by the ORM. This is
>   because it's difficult to estimate the depth at which an associated
>   model might be found.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your model:

```
public function __construct($id=false,$table=null,$ds=null){
    parent::__construct($id,$table,$ds);
    $this->virtualFields = array(
        'full_name'=>"CONCAT(`Address.firstname`,' ',`Address.surname`)"
    );
}
```

Comment: Regrettably, this didn't work for my, and I've found that I've got to use a completely different approach for this. Inside the Employee controller, I now use the containable behavior to fetch the address data, and then I have to manually loop through the records and insert the full_name field into the 'Employee' part of the records array. This may be ugly, but it works..